# PIN authentication not available in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

PIN authentication is not available in Windows 8 after joining a domain or after adding an Exchange email account. How do I enable it back?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, PIN authentication is disabled for domain logons.

There is a new group policy setting for allowing pin authentication. The description reads: 
"This policy setting allows you to control whether a domain user can sign in using a PIN.
If you enable this policy setting, a domain user can set up and sign in with a PIN. 
If you disable or don't configure this policy setting, a domain user can't set up and use a PIN.
Note that the user's domain password will be cached in the system vault when using this feature."

The setting is located by running GPEdit.msc Then navigate to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Logon -> Turn on pin sign-in. 
Set this setting to enabled to allow domain users to use a pin when signing in to the computer.

Answer (score 2):

It's still there, at least in mine. Go to your Start Screen -> Win + I (or bring up settings charm) -> Change PC Settings (at the bottom) -> Users -> Sign in options -> create a pin :)

Comment: Nope. Not in mine. I'm logged in with a domain user, on a domain-joined pc. Could that be the problem? Then there should be a setting in gpedit to reenable it?

Answer (score 2):

Some users might experience same behavior without being in any domain. The same happens if you add an MS Exchange account to the mail app. Immediately after adding this sort of account the PIN option disappears.

Comment: Yep, this happened to me top. I've deleted the Exchange account but the PIN logon is still disabled. Of course the policy for domain users doesn't apply to me.

Comment: That's because Exchange, like domain logins, has the ability to enforce group policy requirements. It is able to push out GPO settings to ensure that minimum security standards are met by the users computer. It does so even with mobile devices.